# Can't align a fixed div in the center

Tags: css, position, fixed

I've currently got a div that I want to have position: fixed;

It's working correctly, but the positioning of the div is not anymore.

I've tried Margin: auto & Text-Align: center but still nothing. I tried having a div around my main one and the outter one being fixed, but still nothing.

Without Position: Fixed it'll center how I want. With Position: fixed; it'll just go to the left.

Anyone know a solution?

Comment: Please add all relevant code.

Comment: Please take a tour of the help center and see how to ask a good question. Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `left: 0` and `right: 0;` to center `fixed` positioned element.

```css
.dd {
    position: fixed;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100px;
    background: lightgreen;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="dd"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Would you be able to elaborate on why I needed to add left: o; and right: o;? I'm partially new to HTML/CSS.

Comment: `margin: 0 auto;` aligns element to center. fixed element needs definition of left and right edges to be centered between them. by default left is 0 and right is auto. when we set right to 0, thus we stretch area to window width for centering element, because by default this area width is equal to width of element itself

Answer (score 0):

If you want to align a position: fixed element, you'll need to add coordinates values to top, left, right and bottom. Or at least two of them.

```
position: fixed;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
```

Then you'll have to translate the element to be exactly centered, since 0/0 coordinates it's located at the top/left corner of the element.

You can use

```
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `top`, `left` and `transform`

```css
.fixed{
  position:fixed;
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  background-color:green;
  left:0;
  top:50%;
  left:50%;
  transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="fixed">
</div>
```